# C++ MPI standard 3

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing

MPI standard 3 was released in 2011 
with no C++ bindings !
my question is how to program distributed computing in C++ without MPI  (note we need also OpenMP CUDA Openacc) 
is there an alternative to MPI in C++ (not MPI 2.2, boost MPI)?
is MPI built on TCP/IP so i can build my own way using TCP/IP in C++ ?

is there open source binding to MPI 3 for C++ ?

or just you must stick to C GTK+ CUDA OpenMP OpenGL MPI 3

what if you want C++ QT CUDA OpenMP OpenGL + distributed computing API ?

Ubuntu and many Linux distros seeks to replace Xserver with Wayland and MIR    both will write special API and layer to create context for OpenGL desktop to replace GLX also  GTK+ will has MIR Wayland integeration          so on Linux if something changed  some people and groups try to fix it  try to develop new solution

but MPI 3 C++ binding i don't find a solution to it

Comment: You know, C APIs can be used perfectly fine from C++...

Comment: As @Deduplicator has stated, The C API can be used perfectly well. In fact this is what Boost and friends use.

Comment: The C++ API was dropped from MPI-3 since it offered no real advantage over the C bindings, instead being a simple wrapper layer. MPI users coding in C++ are advised to use Boost.MPI which offers real object-oriented interface and supports things like serialisation of classes so that objects could be sent directly as messages.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you for your comment yes while i was learning C for the first time from an excellent book "C primer plus 6th edition" and from other books like GCC COmplete reference it says you can mix c and c++ you can call c from c++ even you can call Java from C and the opposite       so i Guess you can call MPI 3 C code from C++ and use it  is that what you mean ?

Comment: @TimothyBrown so Boost just use C in C++ it bind C MPI 3 into C++ classes in an OOP classes   but is BOOST MPI implementation include MPI standard 3 or just 2.2 and 2 and 1

Comment: @HristoIliev yeah  C++ API was dropped from MPI-3 because you can write and call C to and in C++ so they dropped it and let you use it by yourself     also Boost.MPI do this in OOP API  but doest it implement MPI-3 ?

Comment: I have searched on Google and i just have found BOOST.MPI it says it implements MPI-1.1      i guess if i want to write MPI-3 C++ i will write C and call it from C++ or write C in C++ or make special shared library in C and use it from C++

Comment: @BelalMedhat as you just said, it looks like it is only v1.1 in Boost. Good luck.

Comment: @TimothyBrown   i searched on Google many people teach MPI say that you better use C interface in C++ using extern c or other methods they say it is better than using deprecated bindings and it will be up to date     a professor in a university publish in its lectures on MPI that it is better to use C interface in C++ by yourself so you will use MPI-3 latest standard with new functionality    and these lectures with a date in 2012 2013  so i think he is right     but anyway thank you all of you on Linux you ask a question many people help you thank you

Comment: @BelalMedhat yes, I would use the C interface from C++ if I were you. Personally I do not code in C++. Just Fortran and C.

Comment: @TimothyBrown Personally i prefer C and i program everything in C you have Openmp in C OpenGL in C CUDA in C Openacc in C MPI-3 in C OpenCL in C GTK+ in C Eclipse for C gcc gdb make automake autoconf libtool gcov gprof  for C  you can develop amazing scientific applications in C i use Ubuntu i like Linux it is an open book everything for free with support bug reports documentation i switched from 7 months from windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  i like Ubuntu Fedora Redhat Centos Debian   but recently i heard that all Linux switch to QT and C++ gcc will write in C++ thats the cause of my question

Comment: I was searching for alternatives for everything in C  in C++

Comment: Which MPI-3 features do you specifically need in your C++ project? Because 90% of all MPI applications only use calls from the original (pre-2) MPI specification.

Comment: @HristoIliev I don't know because currently i am learning OpenGL GUI stuff but after that i will need MPI so as in OpenGL its preferred to learn the most recent standard        but from your question i think that MPI-1 MPI2 C++ bindings Boost.MPI will give you all what you need and MPI-3 will add new features small list of new functions and data structures

Comment: @HristoIliev  I am new to everything in Linux C parallel programing Graphics so most of time i asked silly questions but these questions and your answers give me experience may open a door to different thing or solution to problem        so thank you     and yes if you develop application in C++ and need to do algorithm distributed for cluster you need basics of MPI so boost.mpi is enough   and if wish more features you can just use C interface in C++   so i know two solutions to this questions thanks to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official recommendation is to use the C bindings, for the reasons given in the comments. The only loss of functionality here pertains to exceptions and you won't miss it because no implementation was fault-tolerant in the MPI-2 era anyways.

Boost::MPI is nice but supports very few features (the most popular ones).

Rolling your own C++ wrappers is encouraged. Elemental (libelemental.org) has a nice set that do magic with type inference.

I have some personal interest in developing a new set of C++ bindings but haven't had time to make progress. There's a StackExchange Computational Science post with a detailed discussion to which you might contribute.

Comment: You mean writing my own mpi .c code and calling it from inside my c++ code     like writing Python app and write the bottleneck code in c and all it from inside Python yeah that's the perfect solution but what about compiling and linking mpi c c++ it requires a lot of experimentation and practice  Thank you for your answer

Comment: No, it's not like Python calling C.  C89 is a subset of C++ and the MPI C bindings are C89, so the MPI C bindings are native C++ bindings - they just don't use any C++ features.  Using the MPI C bindings from C++ should not require experimentation and practice, at least not more than the usage of MPI independent of host language issues.